# Using SVG editor in angular 7 project

Tags: angular, svg

I want to use [this SVG editor](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit) in my project but I need to implement methods and functions that do not exist in this library.

Is there a way to include the SVG editor in an efficient way? or should I open a new project for that SVG editor and show that project in my main project as outer URL?

In case I should include this library inside my main project, should I put it inside the Assets library? Or as a separate module?

In a more general way: how can I use an open source project, that I need to implement new functions and methods or change some of the existing ones, in my own project that a team needs to work on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find an answer or method to this? I am trying to integrate svg-edit with an angular project and want to avoid the learning curve

Comment: @Subbu No. I'm as well needed this project in my angular project. could not find a "good practice" way to use it. I just included the project in my project and used an `iframe`  to get access to the "plugin". the extra functions I needed to include, I had to make changes in the plugins fiiles. THIS IS THE WORST WAY TO DO SO. but the only one I could work with for now....

Comment: Well, I ended up doing the same, its still kinda broken though :)